# How to run Gitlab-CI pipelines only branch and tag?

Tags: gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci.yml

I just want to run pipelines when tagged from `main` branch. I tried using `workflow` but it doesn't work.
This is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"'
      variables:
        CHART_GIT_URL: $CHART_DEV_URL
        CHART_VALUES_FILE: "values-dev.yaml"
        DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG: "dev-$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"
      variables:
        CHART_GIT_URL: $CHART_PROD_URL
        CHART_VALUES_FILE: "values-prod.yaml"
        DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG: "v$CI_COMMIT_TAG"

stages:
  - build and push
  - deploy

package Docker image:
  stage: build and push
  before_script:
    - docker login $DOCKER_REGISTRY -u $DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER -p $DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWD
  script:
    - docker build -t $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:$DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG .
    - docker push $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:$DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"'
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

> tagged from main branch

Unfortunately, this is not possible. Git tags are only associated with **commits**, not **branches**. Therefore, you cannot create a condition for a tag to be created "from" a branch because that's not how tags work. Also consider that a tagged ref can exist on many branches, or even no branch at all.

This is also the reason why the [predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) `CI_COMMIT_TAG` and `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` will **never** be present together. If a pipeline is associated with a tag, it cannot be associated with a branch and vice versa.

The best you might be able to do is to run only on tags, then check if the tagged ref exists in `main` in the job itself. Unfortunately this is not possible to do with `rules:`.

Comment: `The best you might be able to do is to run only on tags, then check if the tagged ref exists in main in the job itself.` - Can you give me an example of this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this explanation. I understand that tags are associated with commits, not branches, but is it not possible to create a rule which is only triggered by a **commit** with a **tag** to a specific **branch**?

Comment: @PhilipStratford unfortunately it is not possible to create a rule for this. You can [use the API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#get-references-a-commit-is-pushed-to) or other means to see the refs in which the same commit may be present, but this information isn't present in any predefined variables for tag pipelines, so it cannot be used in a rule. The only workaround  I can imagine that might let you use `rules:` is in a case where you trigger a child pipeline and somehow add that information yourself when triggering the pipeline, but that probably adds more trouble than help.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the only syntax to choose when the job should run:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#specify-when-jobs-run-with-only-and-except

For example, the following job only run on pushes (main or a branch) and when a tag is created:

```yaml
job:
  only:
    - tags
    - pushes
```

More information about the syntax here:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#onlyrefs--exceptrefs