# Gitlab CI - run a task with only TAG & specific BRANCH

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

how can I start a job with gitlab-ci only when I create a new tag with a specific branch?
I try everything but it still doesn't work.

```
stages: 
  - shov server

test:
  stage: shov server
  rules: 
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "CI_merge"'
      when: always
  tags: 
    - runner
  script:
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down 
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build 
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Gitlab-CI pipelines only branch and tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72040149/how-to-run-gitlab-ci-pipelines-only-branch-and-tag)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not possible. When the Pipeline runs for a tag, there is no variable defined that indicates the branch. You see this for yourself by looking through all available variables with `export`. [Gitlab Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/index.html#list-all-environment-variables)

You could perhaps try to find the branch, which the commit is on. Something like `git branch -a --contains $CI_COMMIT_SHA` or something [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2707110/14906662). However you probably can't do that in the rules, and have to do it in the `script`, or in the `before_script` with custom logic to stop the rest of the script from running.

Comment: It does not work